# Determining the product which is not possible in the reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, halides, radicals

This is an objective type question I encountered in a objective test.

[image]

NBS (*N*-bromosuccinimide) is used for the allylic substitution of $\ce{Br}$ in a reaction. In this reaction, since the allylic carbon is the carbon adjacent to the carbon having double bonds, I thought that options B), C) and D) all can be the products but not A). However, the answer key gives the answer as D) and I can't understand why it should be?

Comment: This is weird. Unless there is some mechanism that I am overlooking, A1, B2, C2 and D2 should all **not** be reaction products.

Comment: Is there any other information? In particular, does it state that the starting material is racemic?

Comment: @jerepirrre no,no further information was provided to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>**D** is a product, but only one product. Not two products. Those two are the same molecule flipped on a mirror plane. Were the molecule chiral (having an non-superimposable asymmetric center), then it could be two products. Not as it sits now.</s>

Notice D1 is the same as B1. <s>D2 is also B1, but flipped. Six products.</s>

**D2** is an enantiomer of **D1**, but not identical to it. I cannot puzzle out how D is supposed to be the correct answer.

Comment: The structures in D are not the same compound, they are mirror images. They are chiral. You cannot "flip on a mirror plane". You can only rotate (flip) around an axis.

Comment: You are correct. The methyl group has shifted from the starting location. Fixing...

Answer (score 3):

@Pete
B1 is same as D1

But, D1 & D2 are not same.

@Aniline
I see some problem in the options while it was framed/typed/published

I have shown the 6 possible stereoisomers, which have have labelled independently as A, B, C, D, E & F

For the sake of clarity have generated their names with some software [not from my own] to be assured that these are actually different or same compounds.

Showing the mechanism, how there is a possibility of getting SIX by a free radical mechanism:

[image]

This one a redraw of the options A, B, C & D with their names:
[image]

The relationship of D1 & D2 as per question doesn't work to the the same:[image]

In my opinion, there are six stereoisomers possible, but the correct option does not exist, in the question[options given, in fact].

Hope it throws some more light on your query.

Answer (score 0):

The second product in Option **D)** is not a product of this reaction.

You cannot rotate the substrate molecule in such a way that the Me substituent ends up in the portraied position.

Comment: @SirJohnson So that means that the two products in option D are identical.we can rotate the first one 180 degree to get the second one.

Comment: To me, it looks like each group of two has an impossible product: the one where the methyl group’s carbon’s stereochemistry is inverted. Can you explain how the methyl group inversion would proceed? Especially since I am getting six products without methyl group inversion …

Comment: Absolute stereochemistry is irrelevant if the products in (B) are not wrong.